# What is the difference between LightGBM and XGBoost?

Tags: model, boosting

I found this post : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/which-algorithm-takes-the-crown-light-gbm-vs-xgboost/

However, they did not explain clearly in terms of mathematical model. Could anyone make it more clearly please ?

Comment: I your question about speed or mathematical model? Those are two completely different things. Speed may depend on many different things, e.g. quality of the implementation, or technology that was used.

Comment: I focus on the mathematical model. What are the differences between them ?

Comment: I edited your title to make it more clear.

Comment: I think the main difference is in how the algorithms explore the space of possible decision trees. Most tree growing algorithms use a greedy search strategy, split decisions are made in a locally optimal way, but that doesn't necessary lead to the optimal decision tree. XGBoost, like most other decision tree based algorithms I've seen, appears to use a breadth first greedy approach to grow a tree. LightGBM appears to use a depth first greedy search strategy.